# Minimum age of קידושין for a female?

Tags: halacha, marriage, maseches-kiddushin, kiddushin-eirusin

What is the minimum age of kiddushin (that is Dioryta) that the father can effect via כסף or שטר?

Answer (score 13):

From the day she is born ([Shulchan Arukh EH 37:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%96_%D7%90)).

Comment: what with לקדש עובר במעי אמו?

Comment: @kouty doesn't work. If you give money to dad when mom is noticably pregnant for the kiddushin to take effect later when fetus is born, then a minority opinion says that works and she is mekuddeshet from the day she is born, see EH 40:7

Comment: But it's worth noting that making use of this halacha is a terrible idea except in weird cases.